# HWUT - exe.txt in OUT file not populating all the read data

Tags: serial-communication, hwut

I have an application that reads from serial port from PC. When i read using my standalone application, all the expected read bytes are received. But when i incorporate the application into HWUT ( Hello World Unit Testing), the .exe output generated in OUT folder contains a portion of the received data and fills the rest will NULL. I use the same receive buffer size for both cases. What could be the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run the application on the command line, is the output correct?

Does 'fflush(stdout)' help?

How large is th output? Note, that HWUT has an in-buildt oversize detection. If you need larger output respond to "--hwut-info" with

... printf("SIZE-LIMIT: 4711MB;\n"); ...

Change MB to KB for kilo byte or GB for giga byte. 4711 is your size limit.

Comment: Hi Frank, when application is run on command line the output is correct.

Comment: Adding fflush(stdout) gives the same result. The receive buffer has been assigned to 500bytes. 18 bytes are written and 18+500  bytes are read.   This doesnt seem to cause an issue when application is run in command line. Not sure if this is causing an issue. Currently i receive a warning " response to '--hwut-info' with unknown keyword".       
                                        if( argc > 2 && strcmp(argv[1], "--hwut-info") == 0 ) {
    printf("SIZE-LIMIT: 4711MB;\n");  
      return 0;
    }

Comment: Hi Frank, Currently timeouts are set to,                            timeouts.ReadIntervalTimeout = 0xffff;
 timeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutConstant = 1;
 timeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 0;
 timeouts.WriteTotalTimeoutConstant = 0;
 timeouts.WriteTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 10; I tried to change the Read IntervalTimeout to 0xfff, when it dint work, reverted to 0xffff, i started getting all the data into the file. Not sure why this should happen.

Comment: What is your HWUT Version? Can you download the latest and check again?

Comment: I still have this issue.  This is how i define the response to hwut-info .                                                  if( argc > 2 && strcmp(argv[1], "--hwut-info") == 0 ) {
    printf("SIZE-LIMIT: 4711MB;\n");  
      return 0;
    }                                                                                                                I get a warning,                                                                                            Warning: test 'serial_comm.exe'
Warning:   response to '--hwut-info' with unknown keyword
Warning:   ''.

Comment: HWUT version used is hwut-0.27.3. It seems to be the latest.

Comment: Please, the first line of the '--hwut-info' response must be a test title.

Comment: The test title is terminated by ';' and then other options may be added, such as SIZE-LIMIT. Did you implement the parallel output to a separate file. Would you please, write into a file what you write to sdout?

Comment: Even if add the title, i get the warning. if( argc > 2 && strcmp(argv[1], "--hwut-info") == 0 ) {
    printf("My Test\n"); 
    printf("SIZE-LIMIT: 4711MB;\n");  
      return 0;
    }

Comment: I redirect the received serial buffer to a file and i am able to receive all the expected data.

Comment: Hi Frank, I am able to recive serial data content into the .exe file. Thanks.